# NiFi Can't See AWS Profile

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I'm attempting to use ListS3 to access a bucket in S3 and I've set up an AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService. However, when I run this processor it returns with `The security token included in the request is invalid (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId)`.

I can run from the aws cli without issue, and both the command line and NiFi are running the same user. I'm just stumped as to why it's failing on NiFi but not on the cli when I run as the nifi user. It seems like it can't see my profilename profile which is already configured with the region, the role_arn, and the credential_source.

On the cli, I run `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/path/to/file.file /path/to/dest --profile profilename`. The configs for the Controller Service are

```
Use Default Credentials: false
Access Key: No value set
Secret Key: No value set
Credentials File: No value set
Profile Name: profilename
Use Anonymous Credentials: false
Assume Role ARN: arn:aws:iam:00000000000:role/bucket
Assume Role Session Name: default
Session Time: 3600
```

I'm just not clear why this isn't working in NiFi but is working on the cli, and I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.

Comment: why do you need the assume role arn?

Comment: @Lamanus something about how the bucket is configured by the client, I just know that DevOps said that we had to. Do you think that may have something to do with nifi not seeing the profile?

Answer (score -1):

One alternative option is to use `AWS instance-profile` and tag that profile in the `S3 bucket policy`. Perhaps this article will help you [How can I grant my Amazon EC2 instance access to an Amazon S3 bucket?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket).
If your NiFi is also in AWS (EC2), using instance-profile is the safest means to talk to other AWS services.